# 'Cannot open display' on restored GNU screen session

Tags: debian, xorg, gnu-screen

Using debian unstable with Gnome 3 but I think this has always happened.

If I log out and then log back in again it seems the X session is restarted or in some way changed.

In any case, when I start a terminal in the second session and re attach the screen, it's no longer possible to start X apps. (message is 'Cannot open display').

Is there an environment variable I can set or command I can run so that the screen session knows the new X details, or do I always have to start a new screen session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you have some problem with xauthorization.

Please check if the value of `XAUTHORITY` environment variable changes each time you start a new X session. If it is true, you have to update this variable in each shell you have inside screen, because their environ contains still the value it has the time you started screen.

Comment: Bingo, thank you. Setting the XAUTHORITY to the new GDM-created database fixed it.

However, there are various other environment variables that have changed which I'd like to preserve. [This page](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/03/09/environment-variables-and-gnu-screen) suggests a way of grabbing the environment variables when screen starts, and 'loading' them when the session is restored.

Comment: @edd-steel I like this idea of automating the environ copy :-)

Comment: me too! I've tried it out and it works pretty well -- but it only loads the environment automatically on new screens (within the existing session) not existing screens. That's just a function call away though!