# Error opening browser in VNC session: cannot open display: :1.0

Tags: x11, firefox, vnc, tightvnc

#### Setup

My goal is to use a web browser in a VNC session.

I followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/installing_vnc_server_linux_mint/) page to install `tightvncserver` with `xfce4`. The session works fine, i.e. I am able to open all other GUI programs. I ran `apt install firefox` and `snap install brave`. Connection is via SSH jump and then port forwarding  between localhost of both client and server.

#### Symptoms

When I try to launch browsers from GUI, nothing happens. On the command line I get for Firefox:

```
Client is not authorized to connect to ServerError: cannot open display: :1.0
```

And for Brave:

```
Client is not authorized to connect to Server[11997:11997:0704/151224.702071:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(247)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[11997:11997:0704/151224.702198:ERROR:env.cc(226)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[0704/151224.705242:ERROR:ptracer.cc(567)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/151224.705436:ERROR:ptracer.cc(567)] ptrace: Input/output error (5)
[0704/151224.742590:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0704/151224.753358:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0704/151224.753382:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
/snap/brave/166/opt/brave.com/brave/brave-browser: line 48: 11997 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "$HERE/brave" "$@"
```

#### Things I tried

On [Redhat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=452828) they say to run `firefox -no-remote`. Same issue as before in my case.

I found a [lot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485955/linux-service-cannot-open-display) [of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20795/cannot-open-display-on-restored-gnu-screen-session) [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139038/x11-connection-established-but-magic-cookie-value-different) answers, but none seem the same. But they have problems with X11, too. So I try some ideas I read there.

`$XAUTHORITY` is empty. `$DISPLAY` is `:1.0`. I try `xauth list`, because `~/.Xauthority` exists:

```
host:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f91ec0372bd83eb72b686a16530ebb43
[five times the line above]
host/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f91ec0372bd83eb72b686a16530ebb43
```

Just in case, I try to set the environment variable:

```
export XAUTHORITY=c441e3e34e057b5a868d5520dc47e7f4
```

Still the same error. But `echo $XAUTHORITY` shows the cookie. Also Gilles states [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) that `~/.Xauthority` is used, when it is not set. The cookie values differ, because I restarted `xvncserver` and [deleted+recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61590691/the-xauthority-file-is-not-does-not-existhence-via-local-ssh-connection-displa) `~/.Xauthority` before I wrote this.

[Arch wiki lists](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root#Permanently_allow_root_access): `xhost +si:localuser:$USER`. I did it for my user and `root`. As far as I understand, this lowers security, but many answers use it as a quick fix. In my case, it throws:

```
localuser:root being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

I am not sure if the error even relates to my problem. The same issue is caused by [bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445485/ubuntu-14-server-and-xrdp) or when the system is [build wronlgy](https://xorg.freedesktop.narkive.com/zfylMp87/xhost-and-major-opcode-of-failed-request-109-x-changehosts). Both things I cannot change at the moment.

By now, I am bit clueless:

- What is my problem?
- How can I solve it?

If someone knows a solution it would be great. But my priority is to have a *browser inside a VNC session*, so any kind of workaround would also be appreciated.

I also tried to [enable](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) SSH X11Forwarding in `sshd_config`. It did not work. I think this is unrelated, as I use VNC instead of `ssh -X` option.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to install `tigervnc` ([Tutorial](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-configure-vnc-server-on-ubuntu/)). Also the desktop environments can be installed via `tasksel` to reduce the chance for mistakes in that step.

In `xfce` Firefox and Brave both work. On `gnome` Firefox installed from `apt` works.

In the specific question, Brave had a snap error similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696600/snap-package-failing-user-slice-user-1000-slice-session-1-scope-is-not-a-snap) one, when launched on `gnome`. Also [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1980734) was also still present.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issues when launching an AWS Ubuntu EC2 (22.04 LTS ami) instance then installing xfce & tightvncserver on it. The default Firefox browser does not work out of the box, installing a new Firefox (via SNAP) is no bueno, hit this error:

> client is not authorized to connect to server cannot open display 1:0

There are tons of online posts on Ubuntu GUI Desktop and remote access options, but none helped - either due to they were for older Ubuntu versions or missing some details or no longer applicable or obsolete.

I ended up installing google-chrome by following this 2/18/23 **[post](https://autodiscover.wordpress.com/2023/02/18/you-receive-unable-to-launch-browser-input-output-error-on-ubuntu-xfce-desktop/)** and it works for my case.

**[Edit]** Added step by step instructions for how to resolve the following ubuntu 22.04 xfce desktop default browser launch error:

> Unable to Launch Browser input/output error

```
1. in GUI desktop, start a terminal session, run commands in Step 2 to 4
2. sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
3. sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
4. google-chrome
5. in GUI Desktop, click Settings > Default Applications > Web Browser
6. select chrome as the default browser, save the change.
7. in GUI Desktop, click default web browser icon to launch the chrome browser
```

**Note**: To enable connection via SSH then port forwarding between localhost of both client and server, I added SG inbound rules to my Ubuntu EC2 instance for ssh (port 22) & custom tcp (port 9501) to accept requests from anywhere on the internet. Add a rdp (port 3398) rule if you want to connect to the VNC server via RDP.

[image]
Hopefully this answer may help someone with the same use case (**web browser on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, xfce & tightvncserver**)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
rm -rfv ~/.Xauthority*

It worked for me